# Casting between character pointer types

Tags: c, pointers, casting, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Given

```
unsigned long long int strtoull (const char* str, char** endptr, int base);
```

Is this valid?

```
unsigned char *s = "123";
unsigned char *t;
unsigned long long n = strtoull(s, &t, 0);
```

It's not generally okay to take a pointer to one type and cast and use it as a pointer to another, and strictly speaking `char` and `unsigned char` are different types, so while there is a sense in which the above code is clearly reasonable, I want to make sure it's not undefined behavior by the strict letter of the standard.

Comment: Why even use `unsigned char *` for strings in the first place? Is this from legacy code where it's used?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Apart from anything else, at least some versions of `ctype.h` isxxxxx are undefined for negative numbers so a lot of programs using `ctype.h` and plain `char*` are undefined if an input byte has the high bit set.

Comment: I'd typically do that conversion only when it's actually needed (ie. when calling `isalnum` et. al.). You'd avoid the need for this question that way as a bonus.

Comment: I'm not sure about _"strict letter of the standard"_, but like you say, it'll typically work. Try compiling with -pedantic -Wall to see what your compiler thinks. And if you're still worried, I'd cast stuff as void* to pass it, and then re-cast as necessary inside strtoull().

Comment: @SanderDeDycker "do that conversion only when it's actually needed (ie. when calling isalnum et. al.)." application here is unclear.  This post is about _pointer_ conversion. `is...(int ch)` are all about `int`.

Comment: @chux : I meant `char* str; isalnum((unsigned char) str[0]);`. And that way avoid the need for pointer conversion, ie. just `char* end; strtoull(str, &end, 10);`

Comment: I consider the type mismatch in the prototype of `strtoull()` a plain old bug. It should either be both `const char`, or both `char`, but not allow you to turn a `const char` pointer into a non-const one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no aliasing problem regarding the types, for two reasons. The aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7 permit accessing an object with a character type (and `unsigned char` and `char` are both character types), and they also permit accessing an object with a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object (which you are doing with `unsigned char` and `char`).

However, the use of `unsigned char *` as an argument for a `const char *` parameter violates rules about compatible types, as does the use of an `unsigned char **` argument for a `char **` parameter. In the first case, if you insert an explicit cast to the parameter type, the conversion is defined by C 2018 6.3.2.3 7: “When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object.”

In the second case, I do not see that the C standard defines a way to convert an `unsigned char **` to `char **` with a defined result. (The conversion itself is permitted, but the value of the result is not specified by the C standard except that it will yield something equivalent to the original pointer when converted back to `unsigned char **`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the type discrepancy if the possibility of a compiler breaking your program because it converts `char**` to `unsigned char**` is a real concern to you.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long long foo(const unsigned char* const p)
{
  const char* const s = (const char*)p;
  char* t = NULL;
  const unsigned long long n = strtoull(s, &t, 0);

  return n;
}
```

In this simple example, I might omit the declaration of `s` and just use casts wherever I need them, and there is no purpose in declaring `t` at all.  Declaring them as aliases makes more sense if you use the aliases often and they save keystrokes.  (Also, with types other than character types and `void*`, you would want to make the alias a function parameter so that it does not appear in the same scope as the original and violate the strict-aliasing rules.)

If you need to pass a value of `end_ptr` other than `NULL`, presumably you’re using the stored value to continue parsing.  Either you’ll be passing it to another function like `strtoull()` that expects a `char*`, or else you can make a safe conversion to `unsigned char*`, a conversion between pointers to compatible types that follows the aliasing rules.  This raises none of the issues of `(char**)&uchar_ptr`.

The code will actually compile without any explicit cast, but the cast makes it clearer that the aliasing is intentional (and suppresses a compiler warning).